# Exporting ROS MASTER URI in shell script

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, bash

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to export ROS_MASTER_URI from a shell script and then launch roscore. In my .sh file I have:

```
roxterm --tab -e $SHELL -c "cd $CATKIN_WS; $srcdevel; export ROS_MASTER_URI='http://locahost:1234'; roscore -p 1234"
```

When I do this, however, I get the following error in the roscore tab:

```
WARNING: ROS_MASTER_URI [http://locahost:1234] host is not set to this machine.
```

When I echo the ROS_MASTER_URI in this tab, it says that it is localhost:1234, which is correct. When I manually execute these commands, it works correctly and roscore launches without any issues. I am not sure why it does not work when launched from a bash file. It seems as if exporting the ROS MASTER URI only works if it is run directly in the terminal, and not through a bash file. This can't really be the case, though, can it??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/332990/exporting-ros-master-uri-in-shell-script/) by [mariyaz](https://answers.ros.org/users/45446/mariyaz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2019-09-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Could this just be a typo in your shell script? `locahost` (missing `l`) instead of `localhost`?

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2019-09-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mariyaz](https://answers.ros.org/users/45446/mariyaz/) on 2019-09-13**:
Yup that was the issue. It's been a long day haha! Thank you!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-09-14**:
@mariyaz: please accept the answer by @ahendrix by clicking on the checkmark left of the answer (underneath the down-arrow and the `1`).